# Unclosed line in a radar chart using ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I can generate beautiful polar/radar charts with the function `coord_polar()` in `ggplot2`. They are a very illustrative way to summarize graphically your data. However, when tracing a line and coloring the area defined by that line, I see it is not totally closed. That is, **there is a gap between the first point included in the chart and the last one**. To illustrate this, let's use my dataset:

```
dataset <- structure(list(Comparison = c(NA, NA, 8.74089490114464, NA, -21.4860528264626, 
-39.2776554202867, -17.6623719989853, -24.6866200381506, -14.7775465072786, 
-7.63468366388391, -11.085710605963, 19.9485934599457, -4.60660415817366, 
-19.826927971494, NA, -3.27723649247121), Tooth = c("UI1", "LI1", 
"UI2", "LI2", "UC", "LC", "UP3", "LP3", "UP4", "LP4", "UM1", 
"LM1", "UM2", "LM2", "UM3", "LM3"), group = c("a", "a", "a", 
"a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a"
)), .Names = c("Comparison", "Tooth", "group"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("UI1", 
"LI1", "UI2", "LI2", "UC", "LC", "UP3", "LP3", "UP4", "LP4", 
"UM1", "LM1", "UM2", "LM2", "UM3", "LM3"))
```

I employed this `ggplot` code:

```
order_teeth <- c("UP4", "UM1", "UM2", "UM3", "LM3", "LM2", "LM1", "LP4", "LP3", "LC", "LI2", "LI1", "UI1", "UI2", "UC", "UP3")

ggplot(data=na.omit(dataset), aes(x=Tooth, y=Comparison, group=group)) + 
  ylab("%diff") + 
  ylim(25, -40) +
  xlab("GroupA vs GroupB") + 
  scale_x_discrete(limits=c(order_teeth)) +
  geom_area(alpha=0.2, position = position_identity(), color = "#7CAE00", fill = "#7CAE00") +
  geom_hline(aes(group=group, yintercept=0), lwd=1, lty=5, alpha=0.8) + 
  geom_hline(aes(group=group, yintercept=mean(dataset$Comparison, na.rm = TRUE)), lwd=0.75, lty=2, alpha=0.8, color="darkgreen") +
  geom_point(fill = "#7CAE00", size=2.5, shape= 21, color = "black") + 
  coord_polar() + 
  theme(legend.key = element_blank(), panel.background = element_blank(), panel.grid.major = element_line(colour = "gray92"))
```

As you can see, I first defined the exact order I want categories (in this case teeth) to appear around the radar chart. Later, I run the `ggplot` figure. I create this fantastic plot:

[image]

However, I need to solve one important thing: **close the line and color the area highlighted in the red circle** of the next image. And most importantly, and I am telling this because I read it elsewhere, **the position of the teeth (darkred arrows) must remain unmoved**.

[image]

How can I modify the code to get these issues?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Closing the lines in a ggplot2 radar / spider chart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28898143/closing-the-lines-in-a-ggplot2-radar-spider-chart)

Comment: @JackBrookes, this is not totally a duplicate as I want to keep the curvature of the lines, as well as to color the background. I checked your link and it does not solve my problem.